# Testcomplete : Is there any Macro which can add multiple keyword test steps at one time?

Tags: testcomplete

I'm using testcomplete Keyword test for a lot of UI test cases. Quite a lot of them has the same steps.

Is there any Macro functionality which can add multiple preset actions/checkpoints easily?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can call another keyword test using the [Run Keyword Test](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11752/) operation or a script function using the [Run Script Routine](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11225/) operation. Both operations allow specifying parameters for a test. Also, you can use the [Run Test](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11758/) operation to run any item that can be treated as a separate test (keyword or script test, network suite job or task, a load test).

Moreover, I think that you will find it useful the Data-Driven Testing functionality of TestComplete that allows running a test for every record in a specified data source. Find more information on this feature in the [Data-Driven Testing](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11918/) help topic. Videos demonstrating data-driven approach can be found [here](http://support.smartbear.com/screencasts/testcomplete/creating-data-driven-tests/) and [here](http://support.smartbear.com/screencasts/testcomplete/data-driven-testing-testcomplete-webinar/).